# Maven EJB dependence

Tags: java, maven, ejb

i got 2 Applications (EAR-s), each of them have own EJB-module.
Now i am trying to build applications with maven.
The trouble is that each of EJB-modules are using own EJB-client module and EJB-client module from another application.
In maven topology EJB-core and EJB-client module must be placed in one project, so i get round-dependency and can't build applications.
Any suggestions?

Comment: What you have in each EJB module? WebService? Entities?

Comment: In your application architecture is not clear

Answer (score 0):

ear-1.ear depends on

- module-1-core.jar
- module-1-client.jar
- module-2-client.jar

ear-2.ear depends on

- module-2-core.jar
- module-2-client.jar
- module-2-client.jar

module-x-core.jar depends on

- module-x-client.jar

You shall not have cycles like this.